# Onepage checkout won't advance beyond shipping method

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, patches, migration

I recently changed servers and applied all patches to my Magento 1.8 installation.  After the migration everything seems to be working fine except for one thing, when customers cannot advance beyond selecting payment method and clicking continue.  It stays on the same stage of the checkout process.

I checked things out with the browser debugger and there are three AJAX calls that are successful (200) when continue is clicked, but the UI doesn't advance to payment method.   The 3 succesful AJAX calls I see upon clicking continue are: 
saveShippingMethod/
?prevStep=shipping_method
progress/

Comment: I forgot to mention, I also had to move to PHP 5.6 and I already applied the Magento Zend patches for PHP 5.6

Comment: Have you check magento log file or console? Is there any error?

Answer (score 0):

If you were missing multiple patches, one of them recommends you enable Formkeys on checkout. Based on the symptoms, I'm fairly confident that your issue is missing formkeys on the checkout steps in your theme's files.

The files you'll want to edit are in app/design/frontend/{theme}/{name}/checkout/onepage. They are billing, payment, shipping and shipping_method.

Add the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

Insert just below the opening  tag. Once done, flush your cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

and go to configs and turn off form key validation.